# Is there a search engine for flights from/to a certain location?

Tags: air-travel, airports

How can I find out how well integrated is a given airport in the national/international flight route network?

Comment: flightconnections.com is another good one for general flight schedules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use Kayak.com -- Type in your departure airport on the flight search page and as destination, select "Anywhere - see where you can go on your budget" as destination
2. In the English Wikipedia, most airports have a list of connections offered. This allows you to check if they are major airlines connecting the airport to their hub. For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_Bonn_Airport contains a comprehensive list for the Cologne-Bonn airport.